# String comparison is always true

Tags: string, perl

Here is the code that I currently have. Running on Perl v5.8.9.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Prompts the user for their desired configuration
print "\n";
print "Please type BB for breadboard, or ACU for the Audio Control Unit.\n";
print "Do you want a BB or ACU version of alarm programmer: ";
$a = <STDIN>;
if($a == "ACU"){
    print("Initiating alarm programmer for ACU...\n");
}else{
    print("Initiating alarm programmer for breadboard...\n");
}
```

Here is some sample output:

```
C:\Users\U157280\Documents\Alarm Programmer>PerlAutonomy.pl

Please type BB for breadboard, or ACU for the Audio Control Unit.
Do you want a BB or ACU version of alarm programmer: ACU

Initiating alarm programmer for ACU...
```

And another one:

```
C:\Users\U157280\Documents\Alarm Programmer>PerlAutonomy.pl

Please type BB for breadboard, or ACU for the Audio Control Unit.
Do you want a BB or ACU version of alarm programmer: BB

Initiating alarm programmer for ACU...
```

As you can see, it selects `ACU` for both even though the statements appear to be correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note: your perl version is quite old (2007), update at first opportunity to most recent version (5.34.0), [Perl version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_5_version_history)

Comment: If you interested in learning [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) then you will appreciate following free book [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/) available online. Extensive [documentation](https://www.perl.org/docs.html) is at your disposal.

Comment: In Perl, don't use `$a` and `$b` for variables in your program because they are special variables used by comparison routines passed to `sort` and the usual `strict` rules do not apply to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Prompts the user for their desired configuration
print "\n";
print "Please type BB for breadboard, or ACU for the Audio Control Unit.\n";
print "Do you want a BB or ACU version of alarm programmer: ";
$a = <STDIN>;
chomp($a);
if($a eq "ACU"){
    print("Initiating alarm programmer for ACU...\n");
}else{
    print("Initiating alarm programmer for breadboard...\n");
}
```

You had 2 issues, first, `=` is assignment not comparison. Second, you had a newline at the end of your input that you weren't accounting for. The `chomp()` gets rid of the newline, and the `eq` operator performs string comparison.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I tried this, but still no luck. I will add the updated code to the original post.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked great! By any chance, you you know an easy way to call one Perl script from another? I have tried several things and I have had no luck. Thanks again!

Comment: If you do know how to do that it would be greatly appreciated as I am trying to get this task done tonight

Comment: I have to wait ninety minutes before I can post again :/. Any way you could please help me with one last thing? It would really make my day

Comment: Why this line? `"\n";`

Answer (score 3):

Following code snippet is an OP's altered code with minimal corrections.

Please include into your scripts `use strict;` and `use warnings`, it will warn you about potential issues with your code -- in long run it will save you a lot of trouble with code correction.

You should use string comparison operator `eq` instead of number comparison operator `==`

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# Prompts the user for their desired configuration
say  '
   Available options:

       BB  -- for breadboard
       ACU -- for the Audio Control Unit

';

print '   Please make a choice: ';

my $choice = <>;

chomp($choice);

if( $choice eq 'ACU') {
        say "\n  Initiating alarm programmer for ACU...";
} elsif( $choice eq 'BB' ) {
        say "\n  Initiating alarm programmer for breadboard...";
} else {
        say "\n  Wrong choice...";
}

exit 0;
```

To run external command or script you should use [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system)

---

Reference:

---

- [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop)
- [say](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say)
- [chomp](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp)
- [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system)

Comment: Thank you, I think I was thinking Python with the ==. Greatly appreciated. Do you know how to call a Perl script from another Perl script?

Comment: As I already indicated in my answer to call perl script you should use [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system) call.